# My Google Sheets apps script that pulls stock options data from Yahoo Finance has worked perfectly until a few weeks back, now throws a DNS error

Tags: google-sheets, yahoo-finance

Something has changed in the Yahoo Finance page and I need help to figure how to fix the linking of stock option prices from Yahoo to my Google Sheets spreadsheet.

The execution log shows;
Error - Exception: DNS error: https://QUERY.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/undefined?modules=price,summaryDetail&hello=undefined
YAHOO_STOCK @ Code.gs:4

Can anyone give me a hand here on if this is fixable and how?

```
    function YAHOO_STOCK(ticker, token) {
      const url = "https://QUERY.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/" + ticker + "?     modules=price,summaryDetail" + "&hello=" + token;
      const source = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
      const data = JSON.parse(source);
      const price = data.quoteSummary.result[0].price;
      const summaryDetail = data.quoteSummary.result[0].summaryDetail;
      const marketPrice = price['regularMarketPrice'].raw;
      const bidPrice = summaryDetail['bid'].raw;
      const askPrice = summaryDetail['ask'].raw;
      const change = price['regularMarketChange'].raw;
      return [[marketPrice, bidPrice, askPrice, change]];
    }
```

Seems it needs a token maybe?, but I don't know how to change that.